# Error Inflating Activity from Fragment: InflateException

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment, and I want to click on a button in the fragment to open a corresponding Activity that also hosts a fragment.

I am trying to test how the Activity appears (after button click) and am receiving what appears to be an inflation error. Here is the first fragment containing the button to view the next fragment:

HomePollsFragment.Java

```
 mLatestTestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent latestActivity = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LatestActivity.class);
            startActivity(latestActivity);
        }
    });
```

And then here is the code for the activity that is opened on button click:

```
public class LatestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LatestFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_latest);

    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.latest_fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        LatestFragment latestFragment = new LatestFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        latestFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.latest_fragment_container, latestFragment).commit();
    }



}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

 }
}
```

The error I am receiving is below and appears to be related to the following line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_latest);
```

Error:

```
06-27 22:35:47.787 4252-4252/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.LatestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.LatestActivity.onCreate(LatestActivity.java:14)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
                                                                                at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:454)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2252)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.LatestActivity.onCreate(LatestActivity.java:14) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

activity_latest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/latest_fragment_container"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

Comment: Your comments say FrameLayout, but your XML has no FrameLayout

Comment: Where do my comments say FrameLayout?

Comment: In the code... `the fragment_container FrameLayout`

Comment: I apologize but I am not following...I have it as a fragment element in my XML. I was basing it off of this documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Right, but you aren't using the Fragment tag correctly (it needs a name for the Fragment class). Your code is expecting a FrameLayout. The fragment tag is only to display a single, static Fragment. A FrameLayout is to be managed by Java code through the FragmentTransaction

Comment: The documentation gives you two **alternatives**, not one combined solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have no `name` attribute on the `<fragment>` element specifying its class.

```
NullPointerException: name == null
```

However, it looks like you mean to load the `Fragment` yourself, so you don't want a `<fragment>` element. Instead, you want a `ViewGroup` that will hold the `Fragment` after the dynamic `FragmentTransaction`. Change your `<fragment>` to a `<FrameLayout>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am extremely confused, however, as the documentation states to add a fragment in the XML: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Defining a `<fragment>` element in your layout creates what's known as a _static_ `Fragment`, and the `Activity` handles creating and transacting it for you. When the `Activity` inflates the layout, it will look at the `name` attribute for the class, create an instance, and stick its `View` in the right place. When you create a _dynamic_ `Fragment` in code, you handle the creation, but you need a place to put its `View`, so in the layout, instead of `<fragment>`, you put a container `ViewGroup` - a `FrameLayout`, in this case - to hold the `View`. You just got the two methods a little mixed up

Comment: Got it, does the Google documentation cover this topic?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's under "Creating a Fragment", in the "Adding a fragment to an activity" section. Seems to be an adequate summary, though I would add that any `<fragment>` you put in your layout _cannot_ be removed/replaced by a dynamic `FragmentTransaction`. I think that's about the only "big" thing they don't mention there.

Answer (score 1):

That because you have a wrong on your activity_latest.xml. You tried to add your LatestFragment to Fragment. You can add fragment into ViewGroup like FrameLayout. Change your code like here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/latest_fragment_container"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
```